# Determine if target can use a specific class Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am working on a project that currently has numerous targets and it's using Cocoapods. Each target is for a different client. Some clients need specific frameworks to track analytics and some others don't.

I am trying to be more efficient and I want to achieve:

- If TargetA uses Firebase/Analytics(for example), the target will include FAHandler class which will be responsible for importing the framework and implementing the calls...
- A class call MyClass included in TargetA and TargetB ... will call any method from FAHandler.
- TargetB does not include FAHandler class
- MyClass will use a compiling variable to avoid compiling errors.

My first approach was:

```
#if canImport(FAHandler)
   //do the business
#endif
```

It seems that canImport only works for frameworks.

Is there something similar for classes?

```
#if classIsAvailable(FAHandler) -> Just guessing
   //do the business
#endif
```

The main reason I am seeking this approach is because:

- FAHandler is an Interactor and no other classes need to know about Firebase/Analytics
- In the event of moving to Carthage, It will bring crashes as the Firebase/Analytics won't be copied.

Thank you

Comment: Is `FAHandler` kind of `NSObject`?

Comment: No, because it's not handling Objective C